# Setting the tab order for Excel textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I placed four textboxes in an Excel spreadsheet and I'm attempting to set the tab order, but I don't see anything in the textbox's property window that refers to the tab index.  The only references to 'tab' in the property window is 'Autotab', and 'TabKeyBehavior', both boolean values.  Here are screenshots of my spreadsheet and the property window for the textboxes.  Do I need to write VBA for this?

[!screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Ogf.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Ogf.jpg)

Comment: Does [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733550(v=vs.60).aspx) help? There's this note there, "Controls that cannot get the focus, as well as disabled and invisible controls, don't have a TabIndex property and are not included in the tab order." not sure if that applies for you.

Comment: ActiveX controls on a worksheet do not have a tab order property (like they do on a userform), and you would have to create a `KeyDown` event for every control and manually code where it should be going when the user presses Tab.  [Something like this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/607540-tab-order-activex-controls.html) should work for you.

Comment: There should be a property called 'TabIndex' for a textbox. It's on mine.